# Linq to Entity Framework with Informix generates useless CAST

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, informix

I have the following Linq query:

`var asnPacApoRepository = repoFactory.GetRepository<asn_pac_apo>();
 var query = asnPacApoRepository.Table
      .Where(_ => positionList.Contains(_.pzn) && _.gueltig_von <= date &&
      (date <= _.gueltig_bis || _.gueltig_bis == null));`

This generates the SQL query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM informix.asn_pac_apo AS Extent1
WHERE ((((CAST('06460518' AS nvarchar(8)) = Extent1.pzn) OR (CAST('10710808' AS nvarchar(8)) = Extent1.pzn)) OR ((CAST('00584142' AS nvarchar(8)) = Extent1.pzn) OR (CAST('03728156' AS nvarchar(8)) = Extent1.pzn))) AND (Extent1.gueltig_von <= '2016-04-24')) AND (('2016-04-24' <= Extent1.gueltig_bis) OR (Extent1.gueltig_bis IS NULL))
```

The issue with the generated query is performance, because the `pzn` column is of type: 
[image: database column]

and it is indexed, but the statement: `CAST('06460518' AS nvarchar(8))` makes the index not to be used.

I was expecting Linq to generate the following query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM informix.asn_pac_apo AS Extent1
WHERE (Extent1.pzn IN ('06460518','10710808','00584142','03728156') AND (Extent1.gueltig_von <= '2016-04-24')) AND (('2016-04-24' <= Extent1.gueltig_bis) OR (Extent1.gueltig_bis IS NULL));
```

If I create a linq query with `Equals` instead of `Contains`, the cast does not appear, and the SQL generated query is as expected.

How can I get rid of this useless CAST statement?

I set in .edmx the property **Unicode=True**:

[image]

but this doesn't seem to affect in any way the generated model, nor the generated query.

As a note, I use the old `ObjectContext` for my EF model and the database type is `INFORMIX`.

Comment: I know it may not help, but this doesn't look like an .NET provider issue (Informix/Db2) but more like a limitation with the entity framework. With Unicode enabled, Strings are mapped as NVARCHAR so that CAST would be expected. There are some workarounds mentioned in the following MSDN post:   https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/20d456f0-9174-4745-bbc5-571f68879e27/net-strings-sql-paramater-type-always-nvarchar?forum=linqtosql

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I used the first workaround and wrote the native SQL query. I am not very happy with this, but since the linq generated query gives timeout I feel I don't have any other options right now.